# Mysql full text search with match and against

Tags: mysql

I have to use mysql full text search on description field.

Now suppose i have following 4 records in a table :

```
 Description field:
    aa bb cc dd
    xx aa ff gg
    hh kk cc qq
    cc ee tt aa
```

Now if i search term "aa cc", then it should read those description where these two words must be there in record. So following records should be result.

```
  aa bb cc dd
    cc ee tt aa
```

How to write mysql `match() against()`  query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your table name is `table1` and column which contain string is `col_name` then you can use following query

```
select * from table1 where col_name like '%aa%' and col_name like '%cc%'
```

Comment: If in database having 'aamm bb cc   dd' data also then it is return this output also, because above query is not searching exact word.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `REGEXP '[[:<:]]aa[[:>:]]'` for find exact word, so try below query it is working fine.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
     WHERE `table_name`.`Description` REGEXP '[[:<:]]aa[[:>:]]' 
     and `table_name`.`Description` REGEXP '[[:<:]]cc[[:>:]]';
```

**NOTE:** You can use like '%cc%' also but there can be complex issue because if you will search 'cc' that mean it will search cc parse in whole string not a exact word so I'll strongly recommend you use `REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]`

**Example:**

**Input table**

```
      Description
    aa   bb cc   dd
    xx   aa ff   gg
    hh   kk cc   qq
    cc   ee tt   aa
    aamm bb cc   dd
    aa   bb ccmm dd
```

**Output:**

```
     Description
   aa   bb cc   dd   
   cc   ee tt   aa
```