# String exact compare in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below columns in my Mysql DB,

```
 id, item_link, item_title, item_desc, created_date
```

In Item_title it contain the title of the item so I would like to check whether the item title is already present or not in the DB with below query as,

```
$title = "Egyptair \'Black Box\' Reveals Smoke Alert on Crashed Jet";

SELECT * FROM  `rss_feeds` WHERE  `item_title` =  '$title'
```

The above tiltle is already there in the db but even though by writing a query like this it returns

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )
```

But this title is present in item_title column , could any one suggest me how to compare the string and retrieve the answer using Mysql Query.

Comment: Can you share the data sample that is present? I suspect it has to do something with single quotes..

Comment: You don't need to escape the single quotes in the double quoted string.

Comment: Refer this here is two answer one for like condition and another one is using regex.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734881/mysql-full-text-search-with-match-and-against/36735022

Answer (score 1):

Better use bind and prepare statement for it . It will escape your string and prevent you form sql injection

```
$title = "Egyptair \'Black Box\' Reveals Smoke Alert on Crashed Jet";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `rss_feeds` WHERE  `item_title` =?");
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $title);
 /* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php